# Where can I find extensive information on animal blood types and transfusions?

Tags: zoology, hematology, blood-group

I'm interested in doing research on different animal blood types, including blood transfusion across different species. What are some resources you could recommend for me?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the Tour. It's dubious whether book recommendation are on topic here as they are subjective, but you should use the site search facility to find out if there have been similar questions on this topic. You will find [one here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30262/do-animals-other-than-humans-have-different-blood-types_) that may provide some starting points, although I am not an expert in this area.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!